# Error Deploying using truffle-contracts: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment

I am using `truffle-contract` package to deploy a contract that was compiled by using `truffle compile`

**deploy.js**

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
var provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");

const contract = require('truffle-contract');
var FooArtifacts = require("./build/contracts/Foo.json");
var Foo = contract(FooArtifacts);
Foo.setProvider(provider);  

var myContractAddress = "0x6139e1b82ffbdbeafbb403a77a04e8374d2521b1";
Foo.new(myContractAddress);
```

Running `node deploy.js` gives the error

> Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
at Provider.sendAsync (C:\Users\y\test\node_modules\truffle-contract\contract.js:24:36)
at RequestManager.sendAsync (C:\Users\y\test\node_modules\truffle-contract\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:80:19)
at Object.get [as getNetwork] (C:\Users\y\test\node_modules\truffle-contract\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\property.js:116:33)
at C:\Users\y\test\node_modules\truffle-contract\contract.js:512:27
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Function.detectNetwork (C:\Users\y\test\node_modules\truffle-contract\contract.js:503:14)
at Function.deployed (C:\Users\y\test\node_modules\truffle-contract\contract.js:451:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\y\test\deploy.js:10:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Using `truffle-contract` 3.0.5, `web3 1.0.0-beta.34` according to packages.json.

What went wrong here?

**Foo.json artifact**

https://gist.github.com/nyxynyx/0c48280e5e881b62409047eedc0d2919

**Foo.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

import './MyContract.sol';

contract Foo {
    uint256 public x;
    MyContract myContract;
    address myContractAddress;

    constructor(address _myContractAddress) public {
        myContractAddress = _myContractAddress;
    }

    function baz() public {
        myContract = MyContract(myContractAddress);
        x = myContract.baz();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a web3 1.0 issue.

Workaround:

```
if (typeof contract.currentProvider.sendAsync !== "function") {
  contract.currentProvider.sendAsync = function() {
    return contract.currentProvider.send.apply(
      contract.currentProvider,
          arguments
    );
  };
}
```

See [credit 1](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/issues/57#issuecomment-331300494), [credit2](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-contract/issues/56#issuecomment-331084530)